# Asking for implementation of google translation

Tags: google-api, google-translate, translate, google-translation-api, react-transition-group

i try to implement google translate in my MERN project but it not work, I
want to know that in which files i will place code.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>function googleTranslateElementInit(){new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'},'google_translate_element');}
</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

i try to implement this in my reactJs project but it did not translate it any thing